# What does "-10 User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

When I rollover my user name at the top of the main page, the first rep item listed is

> -10 User was removed

It is not highlighted in red, so it doesn't link me to anything specific.

I can't figure out what it means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A user who voted for one of your posts was deleted, canceling the vote and thus the reputation awarded.

Comment: Is there a way to find out either the user or the post that was affected?